colimit with two index category
I want to prove that colimit is commutative with colimit, i.e. $colim_{j}colim_{i}M_{i, j} = colim_{i, j}M_{i, j}$. But I'm a bit confused about how to define $colim_{i}M_{i, j}$? For a single $i$, there may be $j_{1}$ and $j_{2}$, so there are $M_{i, j_{1}}$ and $M_{i, j_{2}}$. This seems not to be well-defined. $I \rightarrow \{M_{i, j}\} \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ doesn't seem to be a functor.

Try $I \times I \to {M_{i, j}}$.

Does this mean $\exists I \rightarrow J$, $\forall i \in I$, $\exists j_{i} \in J$ and so do $J \rightarrow I$? @BenSteffan

I don't follow. What's $J$? It means you should consider the functor given by $(i, j) \mapsto M_{i, j}$ on objects (or how else is $M_{i, j}$ indexed? You don't tell).

Sorry, my bad. Let $M: I \times J \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ be a functor. You said try $I \times I \rightarrow {M_{ij}}$. Does this mean $I \times I \rightarrow I \times J \rightarrow {M_{ij}}$?

Ah, I see. Forget what I said then. Why do you think that for fixed $j$ the assignment $I \to {M_{i, j}}$ is not a functor?

You reminded me that I need to fix a $j$ here! Thanks a lot!
